# How do you properly add all the input fields into one ref array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref, input-field

I am creating an app where I get a sentence from my server, randomly rearrange the letters, and display the randomized sentence on the client with the appropriate amount of input fields = to the number of letters in the sentence. I am trying to add all the input fields using a ref to iterate over all input fields so when the user types a letter the will get moved to the next input field. I am still a little confused as to how I can achieve this.

my js file:

```
const App = () => {
    const [sentence, setSentence] = useState('')
    const [score, setScore] = useState(0)
    const [words, setwords] = useState([])
    const [letters, setLetters] = useState([])
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState()
    const inputs = useRef([]);


    useEffect(() =>{
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/sentence/1').then( res =>{
            console.log(res.data.data.sentence)
            setSentence(res.data.data.sentence)
            setGuess(new Array(res.data.data.sentence.length - 1))
            setwords(res.data.data.sentence.split(' '))
        })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() =>{
        words.forEach((word, index) => {
            if(index !== words.length - 1){
                words[index] = word + ' '
                setLetters(prev => [...prev, word + ' '])
            }
            else{
                setLetters(prev => [...prev, word])
            }
        })
    },[words])

    const handleChange = (event, temp) =>{
        console.log(inputs)
    }

    const handleEvent = () => {

    }
    let temp = -1
    return(
        <div className="main-content">
            <div className='sentence-scramble'>
                <ScrambleSentence sentence={sentence}/>
            </div>
            <div className='text'>
                The yellow blocks are meant for spaces
            </div>
            <div className='score'>
                Score: {score}
            </div>
            {words ?   
                words.map((word, idx)=>{
                    return(
                        <div className='input-guesser' key={idx}>
                            {word.split('').map((letter, index)=>{
                                if(letter === ' '){
                                    temp += 1
                                    return(
                                        <input
                                            className='space-inputs'
                                            maxLength= '1'
                                            key={index}
                                            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, temp)}
                                            onKeyDown={(event) => handleEvent(event, index)}
                                            ref={el => inputs.current[temp] = el}
                                        />
                                    )
                                }
                                else{
                                    temp +=1
                                    return(
                                        <input
                                            className='input-fields'
                                            maxLength= '1'
                                            key={index}
                                            onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, temp)}
                                            onKeyDown={(event) => handleEvent(event, index)}
                                            ref={el => inputs.current[temp] = el}
                                        />
                                    )
                                }
                            })}
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            :null}
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

my SCSS file:

```
.main-content{
    height: 75vh;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12.5%;
    left: 23.5%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .sentence-scramble{
        margin-top:25px;
        text-align: center;
    }


    .text{
        margin-top: 25px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .score{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .input-guesser{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        .input-fields{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .space-inputs{
            width: 100%;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: #ffb74d;
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

and for some reason, only the last input field is captured while all other input fields all null. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear to me what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Can you reduce the code to a _minimal_ example? I'm pretty sure we don't need the SCSS.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with the usage of refs here. But looking at the code, it seems to me like you could simply create a state variable with inputs (an array of strings) and set the value of each input tag to the array element, also modify your onChange to update the state var instead.

You can listen to changes on the state var using useEffect. (ex. to check if the user has won)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a querySelector and store all the inputs there? it seems not very react-ish way but it'll work just fine

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const parent = document.querySelector(".inputs-parent");
    const allInputs = parent.querySelectorAll("input");

    inputsRef.current = allInputs;
  }, [])
```